# Powershell getting rid of newlines in function

Tags: function, powershell, newline

I'm trying to run a function that parses a large string that contains newlines, however whenever I pass this string into a function it gets rid of the new lines and makes it impossible to parse.  Am I doing something wrong here?

```
function parseString([string] $s)
{
  $result = $s | Select-String -pattern "foo"
  return $result
}
```

If I type:

```
$s | Select-String -pattern "foo"
```

I get the correct result but using

```
parseString $s
```

returns the whole string with no newlines.  Any suggestions?

EDIT: Hmm after messing around a bit I got rid of the [string] so it's

```
function parseString($s)
```

This seems to work, but why?

Comment: Please add your input string as well as expected and actual output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is `$s`? If it is an array of string, then since you are saying that `parseString` takes in a string, the array of string is converted into a string. If on the other hand `$s` were a single string, it will work ( as shown below):

```
function parseString([string] $s)
{
  $result = $s | Select-String -pattern "foo"
  return $result
}

$s =@'
first line
second line with foo

third line
'@

parseString $s
```

But if `$s=@("first line","secondline with foo","third line")`, the array of strings is first converted to a string ( by simply joining each string ) and hence you will lose the newline. If you have got `$s`, from `Get-Content` etc. this will be the case.

Note that, most of the times, you won't need to specify the types in Powershell. Be it while assigning variables or in function paramaters.

PS:

If you did

```
$ofs = "`n"
parseString $s
```

you will get the expected result in the function with `[string]`.

Comment: @stej - yeah I am sure it is an array :)

Answer (score 1):

Removing `[string]` is probably removing the cast that is happening. You can cast object types to other types this way. For example:

```
$thing = [int] 42
$thing.GetType().FullName
```

Output: System.Int32

```
$thing = [string] $thing
$thing.GetType().FullName
```

Output: System.String

If your input is a string array, `[string]` will cast it to a single string, like the `-join` operator.

To see what is happing, print out `$YourVariable.GetType().FullName` before calling the function and inside the function (still using `[string]`).